# Анализ схожести строк в датафрейме Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помощи в решении задачи:

Задача состоит в том чтобы проанализировать сделки из списка в датафрейме, необходимо выявить случаи (связи) когда отклоняется сделка и сразу за ней создается новая (ориентируемся на дату закрытия предыдущей и открытия следующей)

Проблема которую решает данный анализ:

Менеджеры по сделкам чтобы не нарушить нормативные сроки по ведению сделки отклоняют сделку и создают ее клон с уже новыми сроками

Исходный датафрейм

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({"deal":["EJ3232", "EJ3233", "EJ3234","ER3434","ER3435","ED3284"],
                  "INN":["123","123","123,"222","222","333"],
                  "type":["AAB","AAA","AAA,"BBB","BBB","CCC"],
                  "start":["27.02.2019 15:49", "28.02.2019 10:49", "01.03.2019 16:01", "17.02.2019 15:49", "28.02.2019 10:49", "01.04.2019 16:01"],
                  "end":["28.02.2019  08:49", "01.03.2019 15:49", "06.03.2019 18:49", "18.02.2019  09:49", "01.03.2019 15:49", "06.04.2019 18:49"],
                  "status": ["Отклонена", "Отклонена", "Заключена", "Отклонена", "Заключена", "Заключена"]})
```

Не удается решить данную задачу стандартными средствами, идей как установить такую взаимосвязь по сделкам нет. Прошу подсказать способ или функцию для решения данного кейса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы придумайте себе минимальный интервал между закрытием одной сделки и открытием другой, при котором эти сделки можно считать клонами.
Например, пусть будет так, что если новая сделка открыта не позднее 3х часов после закрытия другой сделки, будем считать их клонами:

```
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"], dayfirst=True)
df["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end"], dayfirst=True)
res = pd.DataFrame()
for _, g in df.groupby("INN", as_index=False):
    if len(g):
        res = pd.concat([res, g[(g["start"]-g["end"].shift()).abs().le("3h")]])
print(res)
```

res:

```
     deal  INN type               start                 end     status
1  EJ3233  123  AAA 2019-02-28 10:49:00 2019-03-01 15:49:00  Отклонена
2  EJ3234  123  AAA 2019-03-01 16:01:00 2019-03-06 18:49:00  Заключена
```

**UPDATE**
Если нужно включить в результат записи обеих сравниваемых сделок, то можно переделать код на:

```
for _, g in df.groupby("INN", as_index=False):
    idx = g[(g["start"]-g["end"].shift()).abs().le("3h")].index
    if len(idx):
        res = pd.concat([res, df[df.index.isin(idx-1)], df[df.index.isin(idx)]]).drop_duplicates()
```

res:

```
     deal  INN type               start                 end     status
0  EJ3232  123  AAB 2019-02-27 15:49:00 2019-02-28 08:49:00  Отклонена
1  EJ3233  123  AAA 2019-02-28 10:49:00 2019-03-01 15:49:00  Отклонена
2  EJ3234  123  AAA 2019-03-01 16:01:00 2019-03-06 18:49:00  Заключена
```

Comment: В этой конструкции сделки могут сравниваться (разница между сделками) без учета группировки по ИНН.

Как реализовать данное вычисление в рамках одного ИНН?

Comment: ну вы же сами себе и ответили - с помощью группировки . я обновил ответ. на будущее, желательно указывать подобные нюансы в вопросе сразу. данный код, кстати, сравнивает последовательные сделки (когда они идут одна за другой).

Comment: Вопрос возник: А с чем будет сравниваться крайняя сделка в группировке?

Comment: начало последней сделки в группировке будет сравниваться с концом предпоследней сделки. начало первой сделки в группировке будет сравниваться с NaN, что нам никак не мешает.

Comment: Получается так, что в конечный список (клоны) не попадает самая первая сделка с которой мы сравнивали.
Т.е. если мы обнаруживаем, например 2 сделки (одинаковые) по контрагенту, то в итоговый датафрейм попадет только 2ая (с более поздним временем создания), а первая не попадает (та с которой мы сравнивали).
Как отразить обе эти сделки  в итоговом датафрейме?

Comment: я обновил ответ.